# why I cannot sum all number between two rows?

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am trying to write a code that sum all the data in a column named `AMOUNT` between two rows in a column named `DATA` in a table named `PERSON` and I used the `sum` function and I use `between` function
and I got the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: 
    Encountered "BETWEEN" at line 1, column 45.
```

the code :

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       Connection con = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       PreparedStatement ps = null;
       try {
           String sql = "SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUMAMOUNT " +
               "FROM PERSON BETWEEN DATE=? AND DATE=?";
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Invoices",
                                             "user1", "password");
           ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
           ps.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
           ps.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
           rs = ps.executeQuery();
           if (rs.next()) {
               String sum = rs.getString("sumAmount");
               jLabel3.setText(sum);
           }
       } catch(Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }                                        
   }
```

Comment: This is incorrect syntax for using `BETWEEN`. Have a look at the examples here https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-between/

Comment: Refer to the Derby [documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefsqlj41360.html).

Comment: Remove `DATE=` from the prepared SQL statement. The correct syntax for it is: `SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUMAMOUNT  FROM PERSON BETWEEN ? AND ?`.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUMAMOUNT FROM PERSON " + 
    "WHERE (col_name) between '2020-05-01 00:58:26' " +
    "and '2021-06-18 19:53:17'";
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but how do I make the date value come from the txt field

Comment: just replace the date values inside the ' ' to ?. the rest just should be fine.